# Capitalize the first line with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to transform to uppercase the first line of a paragraph with the pseudo-element ":first-line". But this is impossible since it's not working on Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129669

Is there any way to do this with jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: Show us some code, so I can improve my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Check this page, may it can be useful

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

and download it:

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/11/15/jquery-1-11-02-1-0-beta-2-released/

Answer (score -1):

Do it with such below: 
You can also get on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/aCPJz/1/)

**HTML**:

```
<p> first Paragraph </p>
<p> second Paragraph </p>
<p> thir Paragraph </p>
```

**JS**:

```
var elem = $("p:first").text();

elem = elem.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });

$( "p:first" ).text(elem);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1, this doesn't target the first line of a paragraph.

Comment: For starters , you aren't targeting a `<p>` element.